# Alterando a cor de uma célula de uma tabela dependendo do status

Tags: javascript, tabela-html

Queria mudar a cor de uma célula da tabela dependendo do valor digitado pelo usuário.Por exemplo A = verde, B = azul,  C = preto, consegui fazer com que o código mude a cor da tabela, mas não estou conseguindo fazer o usuário alterar a cor.

```css
[data-color="1"],
[data-color="2"] {
  background-color: gray;
}
[data-color="3"],
[data-color="4"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
[data-color="5"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Trabalhando com seletores de atributos</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="color.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Idade</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr data-color="1">
        <td>Marco Bruno</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-color="3">
        <td>Antonio Silva</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-color="3">
        <td>Ricardo Souza</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-color="4">
        <td>Paulo Cesar</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-color="5">
        <td>Cesar Oliveira</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você poderia revisar seu texto e, por favor, utilizar pontuações? Está praticamente impossível entender o que você fez e o que quer fazer.

Comment: Onde o usuário irá digitar o valor?

Comment: no campo aonde estao a idade

Comment: As idades serão A, B ou C?

Comment: nao a idade so foi para exemplificar a ideia e por letras referente a cor mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer desta forma, transformando a `td` editável ao passar o mouse. Após digitar um valor na `td`, ao tirar o *focus*, o script irá aplicar as cores conforme o que foi digitado (A, B ou C), lembrando que é *case sensitive*, ou seja, se você digitar "a" não é o mesmo que digitar "A".

**Veja:**

```js
// pego todas as segundas células de cada linha
var cells = document.querySelectorAll("table tr td:nth-child(2)");

for(var x=0; x<cells.length; x++){
   cells[x].onmouseover = cells[x].onblur = function(e){
      this.setAttribute("contenteditable", e.type == "mouseover" ? true : false);

      if(e.type == "blur"){
         var valor = this.textContent;
         
         switch(valor){
            
            case "A":
               this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
               break;

            case "B":
               this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
               break;

            case "C":
               this.style.backgroundColor = "black";
               break;
            
         }

         this.style.color = "white"; // altera a cor do texto para branco

      }

      
   }
}
```

```css
[data-color="1"],
[data-color="2"] {
  background-color: gray;
}
[data-color="3"],
[data-color="4"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
[data-color="5"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Nome</th>
     <th>Idade</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
   <tr data-color="1">
     <td>Marco Bruno</td>
     <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-color="3">
     <td>Antonio Silva</td>
     <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-color="3">
     <td>Ricardo Souza</td>
     <td>3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-color="4">
     <td>Paulo Cesar</td>
     <td>4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-color="5">
     <td>Cesar Oliveira</td>
     <td>5</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: nossa cara vlw pela ajuda mesmo so uma duvida para eu pegar uma informaçao do formulario e add na tabela na hora que ela adicionar a tabela ira funcionar normalmente com esse codigo  e para encaminhar pro banco de dado ela encaminha como com a cor ou com a letra

Comment: tipo : Marco  letra A ele joga dentro do campo certo e  ira retornar verde

Comment: Vou ver aqui...

Comment: pois a minha intensao é fazer igual esta nesse post aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/304274/alterando-o-campo-da-tabela?noredirect=1#comment617670_304274

Comment: Aí vc vai precisar usar formulário pra enviar pro banco

Comment: tb o formulario seria para enviar o  dia o nome e o  horario que agendou   essa tabela teria mais dois campos o do dia e o de quem agendou e esses campos de horarios ai quando a pessoa digitasse o  nome o dia e o horario apareceria na tela no campo do horario expecifico q digitou com a cor do status que ela colocou la e dps enviasse para o banco   . Estou tentando usar requisiçao_ POST por ajax mas nao da dando muito certo

Answer (score 0):

Consegui implementar na tabela agora nao sei como como vou incluir isto em um for para cair em um horario com a cor correta

```js
        var cells = document.querySelectorAll("table tr td");

for(var x=0; x<cells.length; x++){
   cells[x].onmouseover = cells[x].onblur = function(e){
      this.setAttribute("contenteditable", e.type == "mouseover" ? true : false);

      if(e.type == "blur"){
         var valor = this.textContent;
         
         switch(valor){
            
            case "x":
               this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
               break;

            case "a":
               this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
               break;

            case "c":
               this.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
               break;
            case "d":
                this.style.backgroundColor="orange";
            
         }

        ; // altera a cor do texto para branco

      }

      
   }

}
```

```css
 {
    font-family:Consolas
}

.tabelaEditavel {
    border:solid 1px;
    width:10%
}

.tabelaEditavel td {
    border:solid 1px;
}

.tabelaEditavel .celulaEmEdicao {
    padding: 0;
}

.tabelaEditavel .celulaEmEdicao input[type=number]{
    width:4%;
    border:0;
    background-color:rgb(255,253,210);  
}

.colorido {
  background: red;
}
[data-color="1"],
[data-color="2"] {
  background-color: gray;
}
[data-color="3"],
[data-color="4"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
[data-color="5"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Navegador em tabela HTML</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>




<tr id="idTr">
<td id="IDbatchID">010203</td>
<td id="IDproduct">Leite</td>
<td id="IDbatchSize">30000</td>
<td id="IDpriority">1</td>
<td id="IDstartReq">03-31-2017 08:00:00</td>
<td id="IDstatus">In Process</td>
</tr>
</table>
    <table class="tabelaEditavel">
        <thead>
            <tr id="">
                <th>08:30</th>
                <th>09:00</th>
                <th>09:30</th>
                <th>10:00</th>
                <th>10:30</th>
                <th>11:00</th>
                <th>11:30</th>
                <th>12:00</th>
                <th>12:30</th>
                <th>13:00</th>
                <th>13:30</th>
                <th>14:00</th>
                <th>15:00</th>
                <th>15:30</th>
                <th>16:00</th>
                <th>16:30</th>
                <th>17:00</th>
                <th>17:30</th>
                <th>18:00</th>
                <th>18:30</th>
                <th>19:00</th>
                <th>19:30</th>
                <th>20:00</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr >
               <td id="idTd"value="a">b</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td id="idTd">a</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>         </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>/tr>
                   <tr>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                     <td>.</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td id="celula">1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td> </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>

          <table>







      </body>
      </html>
```