# Alterando o campo da tabela

Tags: javascript, tabela-html

Tenho esta tabela que fiz como um teste onde eu gostaria que quando o usuario agenda-se um horario em uma possisao ele pudesse vir com uma letra e colocasse no lugar do um e altera-se a cor da celula  tipo A = verde B = preto C= azul 
mas nao estou conseguindo fazer com que o campo da tabela altere e que mude a cor conforme a letra

```css
[data-color="1"],
[data-color="2"] {
  background-color: gray;
}
[data-color="3"],
[data-color="4"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
[data-color="5"] {
  background-color: red;
}


 {
    font-family:Consolas
}

.tabelaEditavel {
    border:solid 1px;
    width:10%
}

.tabelaEditavel td {
    border:solid 1px;
}

.tabelaEditavel .celulaEmEdicao {
    padding: 0;
}

.tabelaEditavel .celulaEmEdicao input[type=number]{
    width:4%;
    border:0;
    background-color:rgb(255,253,210);  
}

.colorido {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Trabalhando com seletores de atributos</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilotabela.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
  
    <table class="tabelaEditavel">
        <thead>
            <tr id="">
              <th>Dia</th>
        <th>Cliente</th>
        <th>Colaborador</th>
                <th>08:30</th>
                <th>09:00</th>
                <th>09:30</th>
                <th>10:00</th>
                <th>10:30</th>
                <th>11:00</th>
                <th>11:30</th>
                <th>12:00</th>
                <th>12:30</th>
                <th>13:00</th>
                <th>13:30</th>
                <th>14:00</th>
                <th>15:00</th>
                <th>15:30</th>
                <th>16:00</th>
                <th>16:30</th>
                <th>17:00</th>
                <th>17:30</th>
                <th>18:00</th>
                <th>18:30</th>
                <th>19:00</th>
                <th>19:30</th>
                <th>20:00</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr >


               <td>1</td>
               <td>Silvio </td>
               <td>Resende</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>

               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td id="dia">2</td>
                   <td>Jose </td>
                   <td>Resende</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
 
                 </tr>
                   <tr>
                     <td>20</td>
                     <td>Lucas</td>
                     <td>Almeida</td>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>1</td>
                      <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>1</td>
 
                 </tr>
                 
              </tbody>
          </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: esqueci de excluir aquela  o exemplo melhor e esse basicamente a ideia é essa ter um quadro de horario onde voce vai marca na celula do horario correspondente e ela altera a cor

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi de sua pergunta, você gostaria que a cor fosse alterada quando o usuário digitar determinada letra, porém você só tem os arquivos html e css, acredito que para fazer o que você pretende será necessário utilizar javascript adicionando um eventListener aos campos editáveis.

Comment: isso foi oque eu consegui fazer até agora

Comment: Sugiro dar início à construção do algoritmo em javascript para que seja possível realizar o que você deseja.